# Как распарсить строку на подобие xml

Tags: java, xml, строки, fb2

Есть документ fb2 нужно его распарсить, однако во всех документах по разному могут быть записаны элементы например

```
<element1><element2><element3>fdasfasd</element3></element2></element1>
```

или

```
<element1>
<element2>
<element3>dfasdfasdf</element3>
</element2>
</element1>
```

проблема в том что документ может быть записан с комбинациями таких типов, мне же нужно привести все ко второму виду

P.S. xml парсеры не предлагать, мне нужно разработать свой алгоритм

Comment: А что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: @SanekZhitnik перейти от первого вида ко второму

Comment: В каком виде должен получиться такой валидный fb2: `<p>Текст <emphasis>акцент</emphasis> текст.</p>` ? То есть в тэг вложен текст и другой тэг. В-общем, не майтесь дурью, используйте xml-парсер.

Comment: После каждой > вставляешь символ переноса строки

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так мне как раз нужно свой написать, в этом то и задача. И тэгов вложенных в текст я пока не встречал

Comment: @AndrewBystrov тогда иначе немного получится, надо чтобы тэг с текстом внутри, был в одну строку т.е. `<element3>dfasdfasdf</element3>`

Comment: Ищем пары символов `><`, вставляем между ними перевод строки. Код в одну строчку, нет? При этом, молимся, чтобы в тексте таких пар не встречалось.

Comment: @max619 Поставь условие -> если после символа > идет символ <, то тогда ставим перенос строки, иначе не ставим

Comment: `string.replaceAll("><", ">\n<");` или как там в Java

Comment: @andy.37 вот это тема, спасибо

Comment: Не морочьте себе голову и не изобретайте велосипед. Есть готовые парсеры.

Comment: @VladD fb2 от xml немного отличаются

Comment: @max619: Не знал. А в чём различие?

Comment: @max619: Документация вам противоречит: http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_FB2_%D0%BE%D1%82_Sclex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как Вам уже посоветовали в комментариях, можно использовать метод `replaceAll`. Если Ваш файл большой, то для производительности лучше использовать `StringBuilder` вместо `String`.

```
File f = new File("yourfile.xml");

if (!f.exists())
    return;

String str = "";

try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()))) {
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        str += reader.next();
    }
    str = str.replaceAll("><", ">\n<");
    System.out.println(str);
}

try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f.getAbsolutePath()))) {
    writer.write(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно совсем заморочиться и написать свой класс, использующий Scanner. Имеем файл (например xml):

```
<el><el2>yu</el2></el>
```

Имеем следующий код:

```
public class Pars {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Путь_до_файла//1.xml"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.next());
        StringBuffer b ;
        while (sb.length()>0)
        {
            b = new StringBuffer(sb.substring(sb.indexOf("<"), sb.indexOf( sb.indexOf("><")!=-1?"><":">") + 1 )  );
            sb = new StringBuffer(sb.substring(b.length(), sb.length()));
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```
<el>
<el2>yu</el2>
</el>
```

Далее каждую строку записываете в новый файл с помощью сканера. Надеюсь,что  помог Вам.